# Hot to fix HTTP error code 500 received on IE when redirecting user to URL provided by getLoginURL()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

So, I have this PHP application that uses FB Connect for authenticating it's users. Everything looks right in Chrome and Firefox and as far as I knew it did work before on IE.

For a couple of days now I cannot make it work in IE anymore, even though I haven't changed anything.

The idea is simple. When an users goes to `http://myapp.com/login` we redirect him (with an `header('location:'.$facebook->getLoginURL());` command) to an URL provided by FB PHP SDK, that is `getLoginURL()`.

Now, as I stated, in Chrome and Firefox it looks and works as intended and the user is presented with FB's login form. But in IE all that we get is a message that says `The website cannot display the page` and it's HTTP response code is set to 500.

Any idea what that could be?

**Later edit**

We found out that on some computers it does work on IE as well. So that makes it even more frustrating. What's different between 2 different computers both running IE10 on Windows 8 on the same WiFi network?

**Another update**

So we compared the URLs that `getLoginURL()` returns in Chrome and IE10 and they look like this:

*IE10*:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.puzzled.by%2Flogin%2Fpopup&state=80c85248af70ed5b0a1826e4e1662b79

*Chrome*:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.puzzled.by%2Flogin%2Fpopup&state=0172ab20d05eeab382cd5a0f4340fedd

So they look the same. But IE10 just returns an HTTP 500 error code.

P.S: Please keep in mind that the real `client_id` is different. We just changed it in this post for security reasons.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in Internet Explorer only... I'm wondering if it might be related to this: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/491147611024519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've "fixed" this on our side at least... We cannot know if our users are having the same problem and if they have it's kind of sad because we can't help them :)

What we did was to delete all saved cookies from IE and it just worked... Crazy a?